# how to compare two text input type box values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a two textboxes `t1` and `t2` . I would like to figure out how in jquery if the values in `t1` and `t2` are same I can display an alert message. If user does not change the values I want to prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: So the user shouldn't be able to submit the form if the values are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$('form').submit(function(evt) {
   if ($('#textbox1').val() === $('#textbox2').val()) {
     alert('values match');
     evt.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

uses the [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method to bind to the `submit` event for the form, then compares the 2 values from the textboxes - if they are the same it displays an alert then prevents the default action (form submission) using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AYrud/)**

Comment: i m using asp.net.and making form in .ascx page.in ascx page i m not using form. i m using <asp:pannel>

Comment: @user1196392 add your HTML output (not asp.net source) to your question - plus any JavaScript you currently have doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
  var _txt1 = $('#txt1').val();
  var _txt2 = $('#txt2').val();
  
  if (_txt1 == _txt2)
  {
     alert('Matching!');
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert('Not matching!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="form_name" id="form_id">
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" />
  <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[example link](https://jsfiddle.net/anjankant/870k4Ldw/)

Answer (score 1):

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _t1 = $("#t1");
    var _t2 = $("#t2");
    $(_t2).focusout(function() {
    if(_t1.val() === _t2.val()){
        return alert('Match');
    }
    return alert('No match');
  });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<input id="t1">
<input id="t2">
```

*Fiddle*
https://jsfiddle.net/ptda108k/1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
if(!$("#t1").val() && !$("#t2").val() && $("#t1").val() === $("#t2").val()){
   alert("Both values are same");
}else{
   return false;
}
```

I am doing strict type check for input values by ===.

Hope this will help your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
function myfunction(){
var val1=document.getElementById('pwd').value;
var val2=document.getElementById('cpwd').value;
if(val1!=val2){
document.getElementById('match').innerHTML="Your password is unmatch";
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: 'pwd' and 'cpwd' are names of textboxes in html.we get values from these two textboxes and save in two different variables through javascript.Then we match these two variables ,if same then right and if not same then we show a text on html page through this javascript query.document.getElementById('match').innerHTML="Your password is unmatch"; Here match is id of div defined in html code.